# Should I use an iron angle or an iron plate to support brick above window?

Tags: brick

An opening has been cut in my brick wall to make room for a new window.  The wall is not structural. The house is framed with wood like most houses here in Dallas Tx. The window is only 30 inches wide.
There will be only 5 runs of brick above window. Do I use an angle or just a 3/8" plate as header to support the weight of brick above window?

Comment: Plate would be fine in this situation, but FWIW, angle is significantly stronger and exponentially stiffer.

Comment: Did this guy who cut the window in the brick, tooth out the sides and relay a proper return brick and window sill with proper turn out flashing to the wall sheathing? Or is there a cut end of brick at the window opening to look at?

Comment: yes he toothed out the bricks, bu I dont know what is a relayed return brick, there are not cut ends

Comment: Maybe "return brick" is not the proper term to use. What I was meaning is, the space that is behind the brick should be big enough, it is supposed to be 1", that the brick mold may not cover the gap well enough. To remedy the problem, the brick are laid or re-laid so that slightly larger than half brick are used to reduce the space so the window trim covers the gap better.

Answer (score 1):

A 3/8" plate may be a little too thick to fit without fattening up the brick joint. A 3 1/2"X 3 1/2"X 1/4" is a little overkill but would keep from creating a fatter joint. With all the brick I laid, for that size window that is what has ever been used. Although structurally the 3/8" plate would work too, I would still use the angle. Otherwise you may notice the joint grow in the area over the window. Also, as a side note, don't let any mason tell you he can't match the color of the existing mortar because of sand color or other BS like that. Sand does play in the color of the mortar, You can pick out whether it is orange or white or yellow with a close look, but the mortar mix itself is the main influence here for color. They are available custom color at masonry supply houses for just a few bucks more a bag. If the mason uses a "just add water" type mix, it WILL be gray... really gray. For 10 bucks in sand and 20 bucks for a bag of custom color if need be, it will cure the distraction.